# Login button keep refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, authentication

I'm starting to learn Web Development and trying to build the login screen for my site.
Normally when the user logged in, he will be redirected to the Welcome page( which is the case before I work with all the Javascript). Now click Login will just refresh the page.
Here is my PHP file

```
<head>
    <?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "\include\header.php";?>
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://localhost/image/login/navi.png"/>
</head>
<?php
    // Initialize the session
    session_start();
    // Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
    if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true && time() < $_SESSION["expire"]){
        header("location: http://localhost/main/welcome.php");
    exit;
    }
    $email = $password = "";
    $email_err = $password_err = "";
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

        // Validate credentials
    if(empty($email_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT userid, username, email, password FROM users WHERE email = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_email);

            // Set parameters
            $param_email = $email;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $email, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            // Password is correct, so start a new session
                            session_start();

                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
                            $_SESSION['start'] = time(); // Taking now logged in time.
                            $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (30 * 60);

                            // Redirect user to welcome page
                            header("location: http://localhost/main/welcome.php");
                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $password_err = "Wrong password";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $email_err = "Wrong email";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>   
<body class="background">
    <div class="bgoverlay">
        <div class="login-container">
            <div class="wrap-login">
                <span class="login-form-title">
                    Account Login
                </span>

                <form class="login-form login-validate-form" >
                    <div id="email" class="login-wrap-input login-validate-input" data-validate = "Enter email">
                        <input class="login-input" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                        <span class="login-focus-input" data-placeholder="&#xea1e;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="login-wrap-input login-validate-input" data-validate="Enter password">
                        <input id="password" class="login-input" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                        <span class="login-focus-input" data-placeholder="&#xe96b;"></span>
                        <span toggle="#password" class="login-show-pass see toggle-password"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container-login-form-btn">
                        <?php 
                            if($email_err != null || $password_err !=null) {
                                echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$email.$password.'");</script>';
                            }
                        ?>
                        <input type="submit" class="login-form-btn" value="Login">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="dropDownSelect1"></div>

    <script src="http://localhost/root/js/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/root/js/login.js?<?php echo(rand(0,999999));?>"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*I honestly don't know which part to give so I think it's best to just put them all just in case.
Here is the Javascript that I have been fixing

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";


    /*==================================================================
    [ Focus input ]*/
    $('.login-input').each(function(){
        $(this).on("blur", function(){
            if($(this).val().trim() != "") {
                $(this).addClass('login-has-val');
            }
            else {
                $(this).removeClass('login-has-val');
            }
        })    
    })


    /*==================================================================
    [ Validate ]*/
    var input = $('.login-validate-input .login-input');

    function validate (input) {
        if($(input).attr('type') == 'email' || $(input).attr('name') == 'email') {
            if($(input).val().trim().match(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{1,5}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/) == null) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            if($(input).val().trim() == ''){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    $('.login-validate-form').on('submit',function(){
        var check = true;

        for(var i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
            if(validate(input[i]) == false){
                showValidate(input[i]);
                check=false;
            }
        }

        return check;
    });


    $('.login-validate-form .login-input').each(function(){
        $(this).focus(function(){
           hideValidate(this);
        });
    });

    function showValidate(input) {
        var thisAlert = $(input).parent();

        $(thisAlert).addClass('login-alert-validate');
    }

    function hideValidate(input) {
        var thisAlert = $(input).parent();

        $(thisAlert).removeClass('login-alert-validate');
    }

    /*==================================================================
    [ Show pass ]*/
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".show-pass").hide();
    });

    jQuery("#password").change(function() {
        if(this.value.replace(/\s/g, "") === "") {
           jQuery(".show-pass").hide();
        } else {
           jQuery(".show-pass").show();
        }
    });

    jQuery(".show-pass").change(function() {
        jQuery("#password").val("");
        jQuery(this).hide();
     });

    $(".toggle-password").click(function() {

        $(this).toggleClass("unsee");
        var input = $($(this).attr("toggle"));
        if (input.attr("type") == "password") {
          input.attr("type", "text");
        } else {
          input.attr("type", "password");
        }
      });

})(jQuery);
```

[This is what the URL look like after pressed Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBgnC.png)

Comment: Get method is not recommended for passing the import data like username and password

Answer (score 1):

Look at your PHP code, you taking in consideration the request should be POST

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") ...
```

and your HTML markup for your form has no method, which is by default going to be **GET**.
You need to edit you form tag to be like this

```
<form class="login-form login-validate-form" method="post" action="URL.php">
```

Comment: I did as you said but it still just refresh the page instead of redirecting me to Welcome. I notice now the URL doesn't contain username and password anymore. :((

Comment: Did you check where does your code reaches when submitting before it redirect you back to login? do you reach the line where you store session data?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check what you said, but from what I have tried, I didn't get past the login page.

Comment: just try to print the global variable $_SESSION and see if it has the key **loggedin** registered

Comment: So it printed out as Array which means all session variables are unset. Seems like it hasn't logged in and just refresh.

Comment: This means you have to check on every **IF Statement** you have to know where your post is not what the condition should be

Comment: From what I see, I have $email_err and $password_err that are null at the start and will get a value if one of the 2 if failed. something happens with email since $email_err != null triggering an alert, password didn't trigger the alert

Comment: Ok, what is that alert? Did you try to fix it?

Comment: No I created an alert to check which part caused the issue and email triggered it  
if($password_err!=null) {[Alert]}  I have been trying to see what's wrong but can't seem to find it

Comment: Ok I think I got what's wrong, somehow mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt); always return 0, I have execute and store_result before that but still return o, execute the statement in SQL return correct values so it's not database issue.

Comment: Ok so I finally found this issue, somehow my codes were missing some parts (PHP missing getting value with POST, CSS missing a whole bunch of codes) I filled them in and things are working now. But I'm totally sure that I have saved the files carefully but somehow they get reverted when I got back to work (close everything and shutted down for some rest). Have you ever facing this and what's your solution though?

Comment: This is great, but I really didn't face anything like this before, it might be the code editor saving system maybe went down or something. regardless the good thing is it is working now :)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your are not choosing the correct path, please reconfirm the correct path or you can try changing your header  to:

```
header("location:welcome.php");
```

Comment: Yes it's the correct path I have double-checked this. I prefer to use HTTP://localhost to have more control over the address I wanted. header("location: welcome.php"); also not do the job